# BPEL in netbeans 6.9.1 composing web services

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, bpel

I believe netbeans doesn't support BPEL.
Is there a workaround for it, or can you please suggest some other IDE, where I can compose web services together?
I have two web services, one which churns the data and gives the output as a JSON/string and the other web services which will have the input as the output of the previous webservice and visualize/graph the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans supports BPEL. For that please download Glassfish ESB (Open ESB) which includes Netbeans IDE also. You can find Glassfish ESB from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/recent-jsp-137981.html).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, BPEL support is consists of two components: an visual editor and a runtime. Since Netbeans is an IDE, it can provide the editor part but not the runtime. For the runtime part, OpenESB was used to be bundled with Netbeans and could execute BPEL 2.0 processes. I'm not entirely sure, but to me it seems that Oracle decided to drop BPEL support in favor of their own BPEL solution. OpenESB has been taken over by LogiCoy and I could not find any version of the Netbeans Enterprise Pack on the Netbeans web site. So I assume it is not available anymore.

Alternatives could be [Eclipse BPEL designer](http://www.eclipse.org/bpel) (editor) and [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org) (runtime)

If you have only two Web services, BPEL is probably overkill for your scenario. Also, BPEL strictly relies on WSDL and XML Schema. If your services produce and consume JSON, BPEL cannot directly processes this data, instead it will consider it just as String data.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans itself doesn't support BPEL, however there is [OpenESB](https://open-esb.dev.java.net) Which is built on top of the NetBeans platform that does.